# SUM in Inner/Left/Right Joins on SQL Query

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables on my mySQl database which are:

**Employee**:

```
ID int
Name
Surname
```

**DayOffRequest**:

```
ID int (PK)
EmployeeID FK references Employee
HowManyDays double
```

**Rank**:

```
ID int (PK)
EmployeeID FK references Employee
daysEmployeeCanGet double
```

Every employee has ranks and how many days off he can get per year is specified by his rank. For example on the first year he can get 14 days at total. Their days of are being held by `DaysOffRequest`.

I'd like to get *UserID, RankID, SUM(HowManyDays), SUM(daysEmplooyeeCanGet)* in one query.

I used

```
SELECT 
    e.id, r.id,
    SUM(r.daysEmployeeCanGet),
    SUM(HowManyDays) 
FROM 
    Employee e 
INNER JOIN 
    Rank r ON r.`userID` = e.`ID` 
INNER JOIN 
    DayOffRequest
```

But it didn't work. I mean It did work but not as wanted.

I actually want to make a query like whenever an employee gets a day off it automatically reduce the number of days he gets from the total days that he can get.(total days that he can get is sum of daysEmployeeCanGet for everyrank he has.)

How can I achieve that goal?

I hope I am clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you really need.

Comment: I see only the first part of your query and you use a table (User) not listed in you table lst...

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I just translated tables into English, employee and user are the same things. @mauro

Comment: I think i see only the first part of your Q because I don't see the group by

Comment: Where should I use Group By at? @mauro

Comment: After the from clause. You are using aggregate functions (SUM) so - I guess - you want to `group by 1, 2`. I mean the first to columns. Don't know if your db accepts columns ordinal position.

Comment: Also... How dayoffrequest is inner joined?

Comment: By its employeeID but as I said It returns the same values for multiple times.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I added mysql and someone just showed up and removed. @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, but there must be one row in Rank table for each employee because I have used max.

```
SELECT u.id
       MAX(r.daysEmployeeCanGet) 'Allowed',
       SUM(HowManyDays) 'Availed',
       MAX(r.daysEmployeeCanGet) - SUM(HowManyDays) 'Remaining'
FROM User u
INNER JOIN Rank r ON r.EmployeeID=u.ID
INNER JOIN DayOffRequest dor ON u.ID = dor.EmployeeID
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: For what reason you used MAX?

Comment: Besides it still calculates multipled value of daysEmployeeCanGet. For example if it's 70, it returns 140.

Comment: I used max because if there is one record for each employee in Rank table then you only need one of them because it will repeat same values for each row of DayOffRequest. You can use MIN as well should not make differece. Does your user and Rank tables have 1 to 1 relation?

Comment: So for each employee you want one row? What other columns are there in rank table or what exactly it is used for?